# Why is Visual studio treating my .cfg file as xml?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, file-extension

Visual Studio insists on treating a .cfg file of mine as xml, and subsequently reports errors in it <s>on build</s> when I open the file.

The first line in this plain text file is:

```
<HIERARCHIES>
```

And I'm guessing that this is why. How do I tell VS to stop doing this "auto-parsing"?

Comment: How VS displays your file is not related how it is built.

Comment: @qxg You're right. Edited my question.

Comment: Have you tried using the _"Open with"_ option at the bottom right of the Open File dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Open with...* option made me realize that it's default behaviour.

So, my solution was to just add 'cfg' to the extension list in Options > Text Editor > File Extension and choosing Script Editor as editor.

Thanks, @rrirower, for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This trick worked to associate the .props and .targets file to the xml editor.  Thanks